# Export simpleGrid results to Excel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I'm currently using the simpleGrid plugin for Knockout to render data (List).  Is there any way to export the rendered data to Excel (either .xslx or .csv format)?  I haven't been able to figure out a way to access the data outside of when the grid is created.

Here is the simpleGrid js:

```
var PagedGrid = function (items) {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray(items);

    self.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
        data: self.items,
        columns: [
            { headerText: "OrderID", rowText: function (item) { return item.OrderID.toString(); } },
            ....
            ],
        pageSize: 10
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new PagedGrid(myData), $("#divDataPlaceHolder")[0]);
```

Comment: same question here, did you get a solution yet?

Comment: I figured out a way to do it, but it didn't involve the simpleGrid.  I stored the data in a session var then ran some code to export on that var.